# Mysqli_result availability

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can you still use a `mysqli_result` object after you have closed the `mysqli` connection that produced it?  For instance, I am creating a PHP object with a method that opens a mysqli connection, performs a query, stores the result into a parameter, then closes the connection.  Will this work or should I `fetch_all()` the result into an array and then close the connection?

I can find nothing in the documentation or elsewhere online that answers this question.  Perhaps that is because it is mind-boggingly obvious to everyone else but it is not to me.

Comment: I think execution of the statement will make a connection to the database and fetching is just returning a row from the result set but I am not sure about it. You can test it very easily

Comment: Trying it would probably be faster than posting a question here.

Comment: Trying things can be notoriously unreliable - something improper may work for a while or under one set of conditions, only to fail later. So it can be perfectly legitimate to ask if something is actually legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By default, mysqli runs queries with the option `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT`, which means it copies the result set to the client (into the memory of the PHP driver). Therefore when you "fetch" from a mysqli result, you're really just looping over the result set that has already been completely fetched from the MySQL Server. And if you close the connection, the driver keeps that data.

Here's a quick code example to demonstrate:

```
$con = new mysqli(...);

sleep(10);
/* go run SHOW PROCESSLIST in a MySQL shell to see the connection */

$sql = "SELECT SLEEP(10) FROM test.foo ";
$result = $con->query($sql);
/* observe the query running in SHOW PROCESSLIST */

$con->close();

sleep(10);
/* now go look at SHOW PROCESSLIST to verify the connection is gone */

print_r($result->fetch_all());
/* Hey! I got the data anyway */
```